# Hangman on python: How do I make it if I input a letter more than once, it will be considered in correct?

Tags: python

So I'm doing hangman on python, and I was wondering how I would mark a letter incorrect if it has already been used.

```
      def __init__(self):
            self.wordLetter = []    
            self.binaryWord = []  
            self.wordLength = 0
            self.numberCorrect = 0
            self.numberIncorrect = 0

      def secretWord(self):
            self.numberCorrect = 0
            self.numberIncorrect = 0
            self.wordLetters = ['f','o','o','t','b','a','l','l']
            self.wordLength = len(self.letterWord) 
            for val in range(0,self.wordLength):
                    self.binaryWord.append(0)

    def checkLetter(self, letter):
            for val in range(len(self.wordLetter)): #checks if letter is correct and takes appropriate action
                    if self.wordLetter[val] == letter:
                            self.binaryWord[val] = 1
                            self.numberCorrect += 1
                            print "CORRECT!!"

            if letter not in self.wordLetters:
                    self.numberIncorrect += 1
                    print "Incorrect letter. Try again"
```

If the word is "football," how would I make it so if I input the letters f,o,t,b,a, or l more than once, it will come up as incorrect?

Comment: You should use wordLetter in the secretWord method.

Answer (score 1):

keep track of the letters the user has already submitted

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    ...
    self.submittedLetters[]
    ...
    ...
```

Then in your check letter check and see if the letter is already in the list of letters

```
if letter in self.submittedLetters:
    #already entered
else:
    #add letter to self.submittedLetters
    ...
    #the rest of your method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save in one variable word and in another a `set` of this word

```
self.word = 'football'
self.wordLatters = set(self.word)
```

And check letter like this

```
def checkLetter(self, letter):
    if letter in self.wordLatters:
        self.binaryWord[val] = 1
        self.numberCorrect += 1
        self.wordLatters.remove(letter)
        print "CORRECT!!"
    else:
        self.numberIncorrect += 1
        print "Incorrect letter. Try again"
```